# LLVM 15 packages not available after setting up LLVM repositories

Tags: c++, ubuntu, clang, apt, clang-format

I'm running the following script to install `clang-format` on a GitHub Action and running `apt search clang-format` afterwards doesn't show `clang-format-15` as an option to install.

```bash
echo "deb http://apt.llvm.org/focal/ llvm-toolchain-focal-15 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/llvm.list
echo "deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/focal/ llvm-toolchain-focal-15 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/llvm.list
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
```

This is line-for-line what the LLVM website says I should do for my OS (Ubuntu 20.04). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Both lines should be in `llvm.list`, so you should use `tee -a` for the second line to append to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [add-apt-repository](https://askubuntu.com/a/1310730/1577976), unless you really wanna isolate llvm's PPA from the rest (`/etc/apt/sources.list`).

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y "deb http://apt.llvm.org/focal/ llvm-toolchain-focal-15 main"
```